# Can't view a user's other hats on a meta site

Tags: support, winter-bash

If a user is wearing a hat, and you click on the hat on their user page, it shows you all hats they have, including ones they are not wearing.  This doesn't work on meta sites. You can click on the hat all you want and it just reloads the page.

You can test this here: [Main site](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/46271/riker?tab=profile), [Meta site](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/46271/riker?tab=profile).

Tested on the latest version of Chrome on OS X El Capitan.

Comment: It works for me (Firefox, Ubuntu).

Comment: Wait, no! It doesn't work initially. But if I click on the Activity tab and the hat image, it works. After that it works in the Profile tab as well!

Comment: @yper-trollᵀᴹ that's because the hat there switches you to the main site?

Comment: Right! Didn't notice the switch. Even more weird.

Comment: Agreed, doesn't work for me either